# roles.cache gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

when I try do do `member.roles.cache`, i always get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

and when I console.log(member.role) I get :

`GuildMemberRoleManager {member: GuildMember, guild: Guild, client: Client}
_roles:TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
cache:TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
client:Client {_events: Object, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, …}
color:TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
guild:Guild {members: GuildMemberManager, channels: GuildChannelManager, roles: RoleManager, …}
highest:TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
hoist:TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
member:GuildMember {guild: Guild, user: User, joinedTimestamp: 1589586365337, …}`

I have no idea what's happening

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to see if a member has a certain role (the question isn't very clear), try using `member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'role_name')` instead. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, sorry for not being clear.
the problem is that member.roles.cache return an error

Comment: sorry i miss clicked, new to stack overflow,edited my comment

Comment: Oh its fine. Can I see your code? Maybe somethings wrong

Comment: `guild.members.cache.array().find(e=>e.id=="545628105742614548").roles.cache`
returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`but I'm sure that the member exists

I don't think you really need more code, I run this in the debug console

Comment: Hmm.. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: the block of code I posted on the main post is what I get when i print member.roles, this seems really weird because some fields are defined and some are not (member.roles.add() is working perfectly for example)

I just want a list of the member's roles btw

Comment: well I just created a new bot with the exact same code and it worked, that is really confusing. Bad luck I guess. thanks for trying to help me, closing this post

Comment: alrighty, glad you figured out how to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

okay so I fixed it: in the beginning of my code I ran `guild = client.guilds.cache.find(e=>e.id`***=***`"some id")` so it should have messed up with the variable containing my guild